# cat a file inside a shell function

Tags: shell

I am wondering how I can implement something like the following:

```
test(){
  cat>file<<'EOF'
    abc
  EOF
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to cat a file inside bash function?

Comment: @SiegeX: the code I pasted does not work on my side. Does it work on your terminal? My terminal does not seem to determine it can stop after I copy/paste the code.

Comment: @pajton: I want to make what I pasted there to work, since again, the code is not working on my side.

Comment: have you tried typing it out ***line-by-line*** instead of copy/paste?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Qiang:

Remove the spaces in front of EOF (so it's on a line by itself and not indented).

Comment: This one does the trick. Remove the spaces / tab characters (new line character is ok) in the front of the 2nd EOF and you will be fine.

Answer (score 6):

From `bash(1)`:

> ```
> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab
> characters are stripped from input lines and the line
> containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within
> shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.
> ```

It says `tab`, and in my testing, `tab` works, but spaces do not:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat>file <<-END
    hello
    world
    hello
    END

echo done
```

(All those indents are tabs; the funny thing about the four-leading-spaces markup for code means only four spaces show up in the rendered text, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work just fine, is there anything specific you are looking for?

```
#!/bin/sh

input() {
  cat > file <<EOF
input
line
another line
EOF
}

input
```

EDIT: Changed `function input` to `input()`

Comment: Don't use the `function` keyword, it is not POSIX and deprecated.  Instead use what the OP did with `input()`

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that function keyword is not POSIX compliant and is actually deprecated.  Most appreciated!